# Can I transform an HTML select to "regular text" using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have a drop down box on a web page, using the HTML5 `<select>` tag. There are times where I want to make it "read only", that is display it as text only. For example:

Sometimes I want it to be "read/write":

[image: Read/write]

And other times I want it to be "read only":

[image]

I would prefer not to use the "disable" attribute. I think it looks tacky, and implies that there is somehow a choice to the user when none is available.

Is it possible to transform the look of the current option for a `select` into normal text using CSS?

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I'd really like to see what the CSS wizards here like BoltClock would have to say about this one.

Comment: I would say no since styling select is unstable in different browsers to begin with

Comment: How would a disabled select element imply there is a choice when it is clearly disabled and can't be interacted with?  The `disabled` attribute does more than prevent the user from interacting with an element, it also prevents the element from being submitted with the rest of the form.

Comment: You could play around with styles, but then you'd need to cover up the "drop" arrow with some extra element absolutely positioned on top. And I doubt it would work in all browsers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use the CSS:

```
select {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none; 
    border: none;
    /* needed for Firefox: */
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120%;
}
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eG3dS/

Because of the "needed for Firefox" section, you will need to make a div or span that constrains the select box size. It's too bad FF doesn't respect `moz-appearance` here.

Note that even though this makes it look like normal text, it is still a working select box! You will need to disable it some way, either by using the "disabled" attribute and changing the font color or otherwise.

Comment: `pointer-events: none` - it will prevent the text from being selected though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster that does not preclude changes by tabbing!

Comment: Ah ha, perhaps I will disable it and apply these styles.

Comment: Unfortunately, in IceWeasel, this rendered with some sort of implicit padding that wasn't affected by any CSS property I could find, which didn't happen in Chrome and meant the page wouldn't render consistently. Granted, this is what I'd call an ugly temporary hack (which is exactly what I wanted it for), but be careful if cross-browser appearance consistency is important to what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

In WebKit you can do it using `-webkit-appearance: none;`

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/56Eu2/2/

To prevent the user from actually using the selectbox you need to disable it (`disabled` attribute).

Be warned that this is highly non-standard and does not work with `-moz-appearance` for example! Thebehavior of the `-*-appearance` property differs in various browsers and Mozilla even [recommends not using it on websites at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance):

> *Do not use* this property on Web sites: not only is it non-standard, but its behavior change from one browser to another. Even the keyword none has not the same behavior on each form element on different browsers, and some doesn't support it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing would be to have a span next to your select, and use an event listener on the select to copy its text into the span, and toggle whether the select or the span is visible.  It's a bit of Javascript but it will give you a lot of control.

Comment: Then your answer is "no, it is not possible with CSS"?

Comment: This is the most practical way to solve the underlying issue, if not the actual stated problem.

Answer (score -2):

You could create a custom drop down and have a disabled state, styled with CSS.

There is a really good jQuery plugin that you can set this up with: http://uniformjs.com/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question . Also, this is not even a JavaScript question, it's a CSS question.

Comment: We all know you can't style a select with CSS. This is a valid, alternative solution.

Comment: If you think you can't style an element with select and have good citation for that, _that_ should be your answer with how you'd do it with JavaScript as a comment on that. The question is "Is it possible to transform the look of the current option for a select into normal text using CSS?", your answer does _not_ answer this question. In addition to that, it goes against the common etiquette which was decided and voted on in meta. I know you are just trying to help and I apologize for sounding harsh.

Comment: The way the question was phrased did not imply that a javascript answer was unacceptable.  Dylan told us what he was trying to do visually - his ultimate goal - and Chris gave him a way to do that.  It's not clear that Dylan is or isn't aware of the things you can do with javascript.  There's no reason to discourage an answer like this.

Comment: @atw13 I disagree but I am more than willing to hear other opinions. I've asked http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174033/when-is-use-javascript-an-appropriate-answer-to-an-html-css-question in response in meta leaving the post itself objective on purpose. If you'd like to argue your stance please feel free to do so there.